# How to validate JWT sending it to backend from NextJs

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, next.js, authorization

I am developing an application and I'm using Laravel and NextJs separately so when I login if the credentials are correct the backend return a signed JWT and in NextJs I store in a cookie (I don't use any package in next for authentication).

In laravel I have several routes with 2 middlewares, one is to validate the JWT token and the another is to check the user role, if it's admin you can continue if not return 401 status.

```
   // ADMIN DASHBOARD
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'auth.admin']], function() {
        Route::get('/dashboard', [UserController::class, 'index']);
        Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
        Route::apiResource('/draw-sizes', DrawSizeController::class, ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
        Route::apiResource('/surfaces', SurfaceController::class, ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
        ...
        ...
    });
```

The problem that I have is in NextJS when I already logged in as admin and the cookie is stored, I need to check before accessing any admin page if the jwt is valid and if the user has role admin and for this I thought 2 options:

1. have a wrapper in charge of sending the JWT to the backend and wait the responde. For example `/validate` and wait for status 200 or 401.

> ```
> <validateJWTWrapper>
>    <AnyAdminPage />
> <validateJWTWrapper />
> ```

1. In each admin page call the backend in the useEffect endpoint related to the page in charge of fetching the info) and wait for the backend's response, and again if it is 200 continue or if it is 401 redirect to another view for example something like this:

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     try{
>        const pageData = axios.get()......
>        ....
>        ....
>        
>     }catch(error){
>        //check 401 error
>     }
>
>   });
> ```

I'm sure there are other alternatives but I'm not sure how to implement this to check the JWT before access to each admin route.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? You cannot and need not protect client-side Javascript routes, it's all in the bundle anyway. What you want to protect and authorize is backend API calls. If no data is returned to unauthorized users, there should be no harm in looking at empty html pages. And from here, it's only a UX question on the client side, which you can solve any way you want, like for example store the role of the user upon login and show pages based on that.